# Chunked xarray: load only 1 cell in memory efficiently

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray

**Context:**

I have a datacube with 3 variables (3D arrays, dims:`time,y,x`). The datacube is too big to fit in memory so I chunk it with `xarray/dask`. I want to apply a function to every cell in `x,y` of every variable in my datacube.

**Problem:**

My method takes a long time to load only one cell (1 minute) and I have to do that 112200 times. I use a `for loop` with `dataset.variable.isel(x=i, y=j).values` to load a single 1D array from my variables. Is there a better way to do that ? Also, knowing my dataset is chunked, is there a way to do that in parallel for all the chunks at once ?

**Code example:**

```
# Setup
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# Create the dimensions
x = np.linspace(0, 99, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 349, 350)
time = np.linspace(0, 299, 300)

# Create the dataset
xrds= xr.Dataset()

# Add the dimensions to the dataset
xrds['time'] = time
xrds['y'] = y
xrds['x'] = x



# Create the random data variables with chunking
chunksize = (10, 100, 100)  # Chunk size for the variables
data_var1 = np.random.rand(len(time), len(y), len(x))
data_var2 = np.random.rand(len(time), len(y), len(x))
data_var3 = np.random.rand(len(time), len(y), len(x))

xrds['data_var1'] = (('time', 'y', 'x'), data_var1, {'chunks': chunksize})
xrds['data_var2'] = (('time', 'y', 'x'), data_var2, {'chunks': chunksize})
xrds['data_var3'] = (('time', 'y', 'x'), data_var3, {'chunks': chunksize})

#### ---- My Attempt ---- ####

# Iterate through all the variables in my dataset
for var_name, var_data in xrds.data_vars.items():

    # if variable is 3D
    if var_data.shape == (xrds.dims['time'], xrds.dims['y'], xrds.dims['x']):

        # Iterate through every cell of the variable along the x and y axis only
        for i in range(xrds.dims['y']):
            for j in range(xrds.dims['x']):

                # Load a single 1D cell into memory (len(cell) = len(time))
                print(xrds.v.isel(y=i,x=j).values)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that explicitly iterating over the xarray is faster than `isel()`, by about 10%.

Example:

```
    for var_name, var_data in xrds.data_vars.items():

        # if variable is 3D
        if var_data.shape == (xrds.dims['time'], xrds.dims['y'], xrds.dims['x']):

            # Iterate through every cell of the variable along the x and y axis only
            for i_array in xrds['data_var1'].transpose('x', 'y', 'time'):
                x_coordinate = i_array.x.item()
                for cell in i_array.transpose('y', 'time'):
                    y_coordinate = cell.y.item()
                    # Do something with cell
```

This takes 17.38s, versus 20.47s for the original.

PS: The line `chunksize = (10, 100, 100)` seems very suspicious to me. It seems like if you want to load an array corresponding to the entire `time` axis at once, the chunks should be set so that this doesn't require looking at multiple chunks. It seems like `chunksize = (len(time), 100, 100)` would be more efficient. However, I benchmarked this both ways and it doesn't make a difference for this data size. May make a difference on your larger problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The chunking is not really important because in reality I use chunksize = (100, 100, 100) for my real dataset. Do you know if chunking is actually required at all since I load the cells one by one ?

Comment: @Nihilum IIRC, it is required if your dataset does not fit in memory.